# Filtering Pandas Dataframe by mean of last N values

Tags: python, pandas, filtering, analysis

I'm trying to get all records where the mean of the last 3 rows is greater than the overall mean for all rows in a filtered set.

```
_filtered_d_all = _filtered_d.iloc[:, 0:50].loc[:, _filtered_d.mean()>0.05]
_last_n_records = _filtered_d.tail(3)
```

Something like this

```
_filtered_growing = _filtered_d.iloc[:, 0:50].loc[:, _last_n_records.mean() > _filtered_d.mean()]
```

However, the problem here is that the value length is incorrect. Any tips?

```
ValueError: Series lengths must match to compare
```

**Sample Data**

This has an index on the year and month, and 2 columns.

```
            Col1    Col2
year    month       
2005    12  0.533835    0.170679
        12  0.494733    0.198347
2006    3   0.440098    0.202240
        6   0.410285    0.188421
        9   0.502420    0.200188
        12  0.522253    0.118680
2007    3   0.378120    0.171192
        6   0.431989    0.145158
        9   0.612036    0.178097
        12  0.519766    0.252196
2008    3   0.547705    0.202163
        6   0.560985    0.238591
        9   0.617320    0.199537
        12  0.343939    0.253855
```

Comment: Do mean last 3 rows in the dataframe or previous 3 rows (i.e. if I am on row 5, then it should be the means of 3,4 and 5)?

Comment: Yeah, so you'd have
df = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 ]
And you want to see if the mean of the last 3 values is greater than the mean of all the values in the array (makes sense in time series :))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just boolean index directly on your filtered DataFrame with

```
df[df.tail(3).mean() > df.mean()]
```

**Demo**

```
>>> df
   0  1  2  3  4
0  4  8  2  4  6
1  0  0  0  2  8
2  5  3  0  9  3
3  7  5  5  1  2
4  9  7  8  9  4

>>> df[df.tail(3).mean() > df.mean()]
   0  1  2  3  4
0  4  8  2  4  6
1  0  0  0  2  8
2  5  3  0  9  3
3  7  5  5  1  2
```

**Update example for MultiIndex edit**

The same should work fine for your MultiIndex sample, we just have to mask a bit differently of course.

```
>>> df 
             col1      col2
2005 12 -0.340088 -0.574140
     12 -0.814014  0.430580
2006 3   0.464008  0.438494
     6   0.019508 -0.635128
     9   0.622645 -0.824526
     12 -1.674920 -1.027275
2007 3   0.397133  0.659467
     6   0.026170 -0.052063
     9   0.835561  0.608067
     12  0.736873 -0.613877
2008 3   0.344781 -0.566392
     6  -0.653290 -0.264992
     9   0.080592 -0.548189
     12  0.585642  1.149779

>>> df.loc[:,df.tail(3).mean() > df.mean()] 
             col2
2005 12 -0.574140
     12  0.430580
2006 3   0.438494
     6  -0.635128
     9  -0.824526
     12 -1.027275
2007 3   0.659467
     6  -0.052063
     9   0.608067
     12 -0.613877
2008 3  -0.566392
     6  -0.264992
     9  -0.548189
     12  1.149779
```

Comment: A similar, but different error is given now though:


      ---> 95     _filtered_growing = _filtered_d_all[_last_n_records > _filtered_d_all.mean()]


ValueError: Series lengths must match to compare

Comment: @Eamonn You need to compare the _two_ means, as I do in my example.

Comment: Yeah, I did this first, but the same error exists.

---> 96     _filtered_growing = _filtered_d_all[_filtered_d.tail(3).mean() > _filtered_d_all.mean()]

ValueError: Series lengths must match to compare

Comment: @Eamonn The same concept works for a MultiIndex, please see my edit.

Comment: Thanks @mitch! I got it working through this call:

_filtered_d_all = _filtered_d.iloc[:, 0:50].loc[:, _filtered_d.tail(3).mean() > _filtered_d.mean()].loc[:, _filtered_d.mean() > 0.05]

Then the results are as expected